# Why would post_type be ignored in this query?

Tags: query-posts, post-type

In the following query, post_type seems to get ignored resulting in display of all posts from my installation. What have I done wrong?

```
<?php
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    $where .= " AND post_date > '2009-03-01'";
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

$posts = query_posts( '&showposts=-1&post_type=listings' );

remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

echo '<ol>';
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
}
echo '</ol>';
?>
```

Comment: Pay attention that `showposts` parameter is `Deprecated as of Version 2.1 in favor of 'posts_per_page'`.

Comment: oh dear lord, he used `query_posts`

Comment: Use http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts instead

Comment: @TomJNowell's comments make more sense if you watch this awesome (very recent) presentation by core developer Andrew Nacin on doing queries the right way.  http://wordpress.tv/2012/06/15/andrew-nacin-wp_query/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your post_type is exactly `listings` and not `listing`. Also check this approach:

```
<?php
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    $where .= " AND post_date > '2009-03-01'";
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

function parse_wp_query( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'listings' ) );
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'parse_wp_query' );

$posts = query_posts( 'posts_per_page=-1&post_type=listings' );

remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
remove_filter( 'parse_query', 'parse_wp_query' );

echo '<ol>';
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
}
echo '</ol>';
?>
```